# Why does json_agg() complain about subquery returning more than one row?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to select every pet breed count, grouped by their owner and type.

I've written a subquery that returns the breed count by pet type which is almost what i need, except i need the result in a json array.

| breed_by_type |
| --- |
| {"type": "CAT", "breed_count": [{"BENGAL": 1, "BURMESE": 2}]} |
| {"type": "DUG", "breed_count": [{"GERMAN_SHEPHERD": 1, "AKITA": 2}]} |

I expected that the json_agg() function would do this but it returns an error: [21000] ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.

Here is my full query:

```sql
SELECT 
  o.id, 
  JSON_AGG(
    (
      SELECT 
        JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(
          'type', 
          p1.type, 
          'breed_count', 
          JSONB_BUILD_ARRAY(
            JSONB_OBJECT_AGG(
              p1.breed, 
              (
                SELECT 
                  COUNT(p2.id) 
                FROM 
                  pet p2 
                WHERE 
                  p2.owner_id = p1.owner_id 
                  AND p2.breed = p1.breed 
                  AND p2.type = p1.type
              )
            )
          )
        ) AS breed_by_type 
      FROM 
        pet p1 
      GROUP BY 
        p1.type
    )
  ) 
FROM 
  owner o 
  JOIN pet p ON p.owner_id = o.id 
GROUP BY 
  o.id;
```

How can i collect the subquery's result into a json array?

**Example**: [d-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/11248)

Comment: The parentheses around the SELECT inside JSON_AGG make it scalar a subquery, which causes an error if more than one row is returned. A better template is `SELECT JSON_AGG(x) FROM (SELECT ...) as t(x)`.  
You group by owner, but the example sums Akitas over all owners. Would you mind giving more detail on the purpose of the query?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is even simpler.

```sql
select jsonb_agg(t) from 
(
 select type, jsonb_object_agg(breed, cnt) breed_count 
 from 
 (
  select type, breed, count(*) cnt
  from pet
  group by type, breed
 ) t
 group by type
) t;
```

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hkmwzKqBbrYArRKtYrtq2E/0)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another, more optimal way to do it with [`jsonb_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) and [`json_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select jsonb_build_object(
            'type',
            type,
            'breed_count',
            json_agg(jsonb_build_object(breed, cnt))
       ) as breed_by_type
            
from (
  select type, breed, count(*) as cnt
  from pet
  group by type, breed
) as s
group by type;
```

Results :

```
breed_by_type
--------------
{"type":"CAT","breed_count":[{"BURMESE":2},{"BENGAl":1}]}
{"type":"DOG","breed_count":[{"AKITA":2},{"GERMAN_SHEPHERD":1}]}
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iE31G9Yyjxuo11uVm1158D/0)

Comment: Thanks but i need the breed and count as a single object. Also it doesnt answer my question which is how can i collect these rows into a single one as an array.